# Cannot create an instance of "KinectViewer"

Tags: c#, kinect

I'm trying to run the [Kinect Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855378.aspx), I could run it before. But it suddenly failed to display the designer for the whole Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers project. The other one could be opened just fine. Here's the markup

```
<l:KinectViewer x:Class="Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers.KinectDepthViewer"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.WpfViewers"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Loaded="KinectViewer_Loaded"
         Unloaded="KinectViewer_Unloaded"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Image Name="kinectDepthImage" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5"
       RenderTransform="{Binding HorizontalScaleTransform,
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type l:KinectViewer}}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
</Image>
```

I get the error

> Cannot create an instance of "KinectViewer"

and inside the designer,

> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.InstanceBuilderOperations.InstantiateType(Type type, Boolean supportInternal)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.InstantiateTargetType(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.FrameworkElementInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfDesigner.InstanceBuilders.UserControlInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(IInstanceBuilderContext context, ViewNode viewNode)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance(IInstanceBuilder builder, ViewNode viewNode)

project file [here](https://mega.nz/#!u1hDSJKC!J6g_kz3f0DYpLY8RGMaty1hs8sY3WtadnUWDy5hvVew)

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. Seems like this is a bug. Update to VS2015 Update 2 solved this.